# Spark Dataframe: optimal way of filter/except operations

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark

There is main dataframe: dfMain.

I need to select from this 2 pieces of data for applying to each one 2 different operations. And know in advance, that one piece (selected by A-criteria) is large, than another one.

Which way is more effective:

1. Select the large piece of data, and then except selected data from dfMain (to retrieve the smaller piece).

   ```
   val large = dfMain.filter(col("data")==="criteriaA")

    large.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

    large
     .write
     .parquet("storeA")

    dtMain.except(large)
       .write
       .parquet("storeB")
   ```
2. Select the small piece of data, and then except selected data from dfMain (to retrieve the large piece).

   ```
   val small = dfMain.filter(col("data")==="criteriaB")

    small.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

    small
     .write
     .parquet("storeB")

    dtMain.except(small)
       .write
       .parquet("storeA")
   ```

Something tells me, that first way cheaper, but I have some doubts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

maybe it will be better to create two separate df with two separate filters

```
val small = dfMain.filter(col("data")==="criteriaB")  
val large = dfMain.filter(col("data")==="criteriaA")  
//and later do what you want and store them separately
```

when you use except i think that i will be resolved to anti-join and i think that two filters are going to be more efficient if you just want to split df into two parts

Edit: i did one simple test, here is sample code

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "10")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold", -1)
val data = Seq(("test", 3),("test", 3), ("test2", 5), ("test3", 7), ("test55", 86))
val dfMain = data.toDF("Name", "Value")

val large = dfMain.filter(col("Value")===lit(5))

large.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK)

large.show
dfMain.except(large).show
```

I changed writes to show but is shouldnt change anything, type of actions has no effect here i think

autoBroadcastJoinTreshold is set to -1 to turn off broadcast join as most likely for bigger datasets its not going to be used by Spark

Here is execution plan

[image]

So with except Spark is going to read data two times anyway and later except is translated into left anti join for wich Spark is most likely going to choose SMJ (sort-merge join) which requires the data to be shuffled and sorted.

When i use two filters instead of except there is no need to shuffle the data, Spark is only going to read source two times (so the same as in except scenario) with two separate filters which most probably are going to be pushed to source anyway (depends on source ofc)

Comment: May be, its better, indeed, considering that both in filter and except case we need to iterate over all elements of dataframe, plus bear some costs for persist (and further unpersist) operations.

Comment: I added simple test to check what is the plan in case of version with except, you can find more details in my edited answer